# Assertion failure: calling a list's node deconstructor

Tags: c++, list, assertion

I am a computer science student with the task of creating a dynamic data structure, linked lists. I am currently working on a singly linked list and have successfully built the functionality to add, remove and dump all node data.

However, remembering that my 'advanced programming' lecturer stated that in order to avoid confusion and other problems, when deleting nodes from a list, or releasing any object's memory, you should have it happen inside its deconstructor. So I moved:

```
delete[] _del;
```

Which worked fine and moved it to the nodes' deconstructor:

```
#include "Node.h"

// Node.cpp

Node::Node(const int &inData, const int &inId)
{
    _id = inId;
    _data = inData;
    nextNode = NULL;
}

// Deconstructor to delete the node when using List.Del()
Node::~Node()
{
    delete[] this;
}
```

In my List the node's deconstructor is called via a pointer like so:

```
_del->~Node();
```

Which gives me an assertion error. I'm assuming it is my usage of 'this' in the node's deconstructor?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should not call an objects destructor directly, unless you're writing an allocator and used placement new when creating it. Second, you should `delete` and not `delete[]` unless you also used `new[]`. And finally, `delete this` is a bad habit, but legal according to the standard. Why don't you just call `delete theNode` instead of all of this?

EDIT: Addressing some comments/additional questions.

To allocate a single instance on heap, you use `theNode = new Node`. The returned pointer must be freed with `delete theNode`. Calling new will allocate memory and then call `Node::Node()`, the constructor, so that it can setup it's internal state. Calling delete will call `Node::~Node()` and then free the allocated memory. The destructor is responsible for cleaning up anything Node uses, but not the memory used by Node itself.

To allocate an array of nodes, you use `theNodes = new Node[10];`. You delete these with `delete[] theNodes`. Mixing new/delete with new[]/delete[] is undefined behaviour.

Placement new is a method where you want to construct an object in *already allocated memory*. In this case, you have the only good reason for calling a destructor directly, you want to deconstruct an object (aka letting it clean itself up) *without* also freeing the memory allocated for it.

Calling `delete this` is legal in e.g. a `Suicide()` function, as long as you do not refer to "this" or any members of the deleted instance after the call to `delete this`. This is a valid technique e.g. in reference counted objects, but is often considered something you should avoid unless you really need it.

The correct solution for you is pretty plain, where you now call `~Node`, simply call `delete theNode` instead.

Comment: I have called new. This is a dynamic data structure. Each node is instantiated with new. Maybe I should have pasted the rest of my code. Originally I did call delete[] theNode but thought it improper due to remembering my lecturer speaking about using deconstructors to make life more simple.

Comment: Thanks Erik. I'll use delete from now on for single objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
Node::~Node()
{
    delete[] this;
}
```

Undefined behavior. Most likely will crash your program!

By the way, there is a difference between `delete this` and `delete[] this`. While `delete this` might be [okay sometime](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.15), but `delete[] this` is not, as `this` can never be allocated using `new[]`. **It's not a pointer to an array. It's a pointer to ONE object!**

Comment: So I was correct in assuming my 'this' usage was incorrect? How is an object deleted from within its deconstructor, correctly?

Comment: @Fred: the behavior after this is not defined, so technically it should be UB. No?

Comment: @Fred: Interesting. How exactly?

Comment: @Lee: You call `delete` on pointers which are member of your class, not on `this` pointer itself. If your class doesn't have pointers allocated with memory, then your destructor should do nothing. Of course, if there is any resource other than memory, you should release them.

Comment: OK thanks people. I understand. I thought 'this' stab in the dark would be a bit wobbly :)

Comment: @Nawaz: No, it's not the array form that makes this UB; "this" could be the first object in an array of length one allocated by new[] (e.g. `(new Node[1]())->~Node()`). It's never okay to use the non-array "delete this" in a dtor either, because of the real problem: delete expressions call dtors, so you have infinite recursion.

Comment: @Fred: That I understand. But I was pointing out the most obvious difference between `delete[] this` and `delete this`. I was merely adding an extra information,not related to destructor, but in general. Anyway, thanks for reaffirming it.

Comment: @Nawaz: I think you've misunderstood; I wasn't reaffirming anything.  What you have above is wrong.  "This" *can* be allocated using new[] (I gave an example in my last comment).  The code being UB has *nothing* to do with delete[] vs delete.  For example, here's a program with no UB: http://codepad.org/IynPD9Nn.

Comment: @Fred: By the way, even if `this` is the first object in the array, `delete[] this` is not correct. I think there is a difference between `delete[] this` and `delete[] &this`.

Comment: @Nawaz: Given a pointer to the first item in an array that needs to be deleted, how is delete[] that_pointer not correct?  The only twist here is that_pointer is "this", but that has nothing to do with delete.  You can't take the address of "this", so I'm not sure what you're trying to point out there.  (Actually, the lifetime mangling that codepad.org example does may technically be UB, but not because of delete[].)

Answer (score 1):

> How is an object deleted from within its deconstructor, correctly?

It's not.  A destructor cleans up the resources *owned by* an object, not the object itself.

You should remove the use of delete and whatever allocated the Node (your list class?) had better be responsible to deallocate it.  The easiest way to do this is have exactly one point in your list class that allocates and adds nodes to the list, and exactly one point that removes and deallocates nodes (the mentioned Del method).  Have your list class' destructor call Del repeatedly until the list is empty.

Comment: I see. So a separate List method dealing with the delete would be a better solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049957/assertion-failure-calling-a-lists-node-deconstructor/5049965#5049965) suggests your deconstructor is undefined behaviour. For the following reason:

When

```
delete[] _del;
```

is executed. it attempts to delete the same object, which you are trying to delete in its deconstructor

```
delete[] this;
```

What your course text means is that, IF you want to clear up any memory associated tothe object being deleted that should be released in this object's deconstructor as well. For example if id and/or data were pointers:

```
Node::~Node()
{
   delete _id;
   delete _data;
}
```

Comment: Nawaz is correct, id and data are private member variables each node holds. Am I confusing deletion with memory releasing? I'm sure there is some importance to doing something with deconstructor for ease of use. If it is more appropriate for the List class itself to deal with the deletion, I will just construct another method for it.

Comment: I wrote For example before that. I have now specified it further by writing 'if id and/or data were pointers'. The intention was to elaborate what the course text probably means.

Comment: Hm, interesting. Each of my nodes contain a pointer to the next. Would this is relevant to this post Ozair? I assign a node's *nextNode as NULL when it is the _tail node, but what if I delete a node in the middle? Would delete also delete the nextNode pointer as well as the node it's within?

Comment: @Lee: No it won't. That part should be dealt in the code that has called the destructor before it attempts to delete this object.

Ideally since the data and id were passed to this object in constructor, I would deal with the memory release in the caller's body.

I would only delete 'new'/memory allocations in a destructor if they were allocated in my constructor.